# SSIS delimeter not working properly

Tags: ssis

When reading in a text file delimited with "ß" and I set up my SSIS package as shown below

[image]

And this is the output data on the database table

[image]

The text file looks like this..

[image]

I tried playing around with all the "row delimiter" options and nothing helps

Has anyone came a across this problem? Is there any missing steps etc?

Isn't the delimiter character supposed to be ignored and not copied to the database?

Comment: Have you tried using `ß{CR}{LF}`as row delimiter value? Because from the text file screenshot there seems to be no final column to delimit.

Comment: Wow, that was genius. It works !!! Thanks much